# Installing Sphinx on Mac OS with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, mac, configuration

We have:

- Sphinx 2.0.3
- Mac OS 10.6.8
- XAMPP 1.7.3 (with MySQL 5.1.44)

Here is PATH:

```
user:sphinx-2.0.3-release user$ echo $PATH
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/android-sd
k-macosx/platform-tools:/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Applications/SenchaSDKTool
s-1.2.3/appbuilder:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-1.2.3/jsbuilder:/Applications/SenchaSDKToo
ls-1.2.3/command:/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-1.2.3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/loc
al/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Here is mysql_config:

```
user:~ user$ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config ; exit;
Usage: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
                                --cflags [-I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql
                                -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib
                                -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE
                                -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT
                                -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL]
                                --include [-I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql]
                                --libs [-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include
                                -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz
                                -lm]
                                --libs_r [-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include
                                -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient_r -lz
                                -lm]
                                --plugindir [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql/plugin]
                                --socket [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock]
                                --port [0]
                                --version [5.1.44]
                                --libmysqld-libs [-L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib
                                -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include -mmacosx-version-min=10.4
                                -L/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/mysql -lmysqld -ldl -lz -lm]
logout
```

Here configuring result:

```
user:sphinx-2.0.3-release user$ ./configure --with-mysql=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles

checking build environment
--------------------------

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no

checking for compiler programs
------------------------------

checking whether to compile debug version... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib

checking for header files
-------------------------

checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking netinet/in.h usability... yes
checking netinet/in.h presence... yes
checking for netinet/in.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/file.h usability... yes
checking sys/file.h presence... yes
checking for sys/file.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking expat.h usability... yes
checking expat.h presence... yes
checking for expat.h... yes
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking sql.h usability... yes
checking sql.h presence... yes
checking for sql.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes

checking for types
------------------

checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... yes
checking for _Bool... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes

checking for library functions
------------------------------

checking for pid_t... yes
checking vfork.h usability... no
checking vfork.h presence... no
checking for vfork.h... no
checking for fork... yes
checking for vfork... yes
checking for working fork... yes
checking for working vfork... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... (cached) yes
checking types of arguments for select... int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... no
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for library containing setsockopt... none required
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
checking for library containing XML_Parse... -lexpat
checking for library containing iconv... -liconv
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for library containing logf... none required
checking for dup2... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for logf... yes
checking for pread... yes
checking for backtrace... yes
checking for backtrace_symbols... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... no
checking for clock_gettime... no
checking for LOCK_EX in sys/file.h... yes
checking for F_SETLKW in fcntl.h... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for dlopen... yes
checking for dlerror... yes

configuring Sphinx
------------------

checking for CFLAGS needed for pthreads... none
checking for LIBS needed for pthreads... -lpthread
checking for pthreads... found
checking for pthread_mutex_timedlock... no
checking whether to compile with MySQL support... yes
checking for mysql_config... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_real_connect... no
checking for mysql_real_connect... no
checking MySQL include files... configure: error: missing include files.

**
ERROR: cannot find MySQL include files.

Check that you do have MySQL include files installed.
The package name is typically 'mysql-devel'.

If include files are installed on your system, but you are still getting
this message, you should do one of the following:

1) either specify includes location explicitly, using --with-mysql-includes;
2) or specify MySQL installation root location explicitly, using --with-mysql;
3) or make sure that the path to 'mysql_config' program is listed in
            your PATH environment variable.

To disable MySQL support, use --without-mysql option.
**
```

Question is: What's wrong? I also tried this:

```
$ ./configure --with-mysql-includes=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql
```

or this:

```
$ ./configure --with-mysql=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
```

Result is the same.

Comment: Would homebrew be an option: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew then simply brew install sphinx ? it handels most deps pretty well I find.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  I ended up re-compiling mySQL and it worked.